# Springbatch - Modifying my application so I can pass JobParameters to my Setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I currently have springbatch application like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}
}
```

I have a repository config file that uses an h2 db locally for maintaining the job repository, creating the joblauncher, and other things. The salient part for this post is:

```
protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {

    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

Finally, I have job bean in another config file:

```
@Bean
public Job databaseCursorJob(@Qualifier("databaseCursorStep") Step exampleJobStep,
                             JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("databaseCursorJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(exampleJobStep)
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

I need to be able to pass jobparameters like:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addDate("date", new Date())
            .toJobParameters();
```

, mostly just to ensure uniqueness for each job instance. However, my problem is that I cannot figure out how to tweak my application to pass these to the job. I typically see these passed in run method of job launcher like:

```
jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
```

, but I never actually ever call that method, as I guess because I use the springboot application, it is done sort under the covers presumably via the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation on the app.

So, I need to reconfigure my application to change how the job is launched to be able to pass the jobparameters. However I have been unsuccessful in figuring that out. I would be greatful for any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/issues/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have a solution. This was pointed out to me by my good friend Mr Hassine who seems to have a knack for uncovering solutions for springbatch that I could not uncover myself!

Following Mr Hsssine's link: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/issues/15

I took my original application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

, and substituted:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = applicationContext.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job = applicationContext.getBean(Job.class);

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addDate("date", new Date())
            .toJobParameters();

    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
}
```

}

Additionally, I had to add:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

to my application.properties, which forces springboot to bypass the auto-magic jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters), and instead seeks out any alternative launching as I provided in my main class in the above code. This way, I could directly add the jobParameter which adds a timestamp to ensure each job instance is uniquely identified which (hopefully) will prevent vain attempts on the part of spring to try re-starting orphaned job instances with old job instance identifiers.